# Firebase API issue with AngularJS website example project

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, angularfire

Beginning to dive into AngularJS so I went to their website, but got stuck on the [wire up a backend](https://angularjs.org/#wire-up-a-backend) portion where Angular uses Firebase. The first issue came from the ordering of dependencies:

`angular.module('project', ['ngRoute', 'firebase'])`

changed to

`angular.module('project', ['firebase', 'ngRoute'])`

But now it's telling my that `$add`, in my `$scope.save` call, is undefined.

Similar `$add undefined` questions are [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26435066/angularfire-add-typeerror-undefined-is-not-a-function) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18864017/undefined-is-not-a-function-error-using-angularfire), but neither seem to apply.

Note: I'm running node's `http-server`, so I'm assuming it's not a localhost problem.

**Scripts**

```
angular.module('project', ['firebase', 'ngRoute'])

.value('fbURL', 'https://unique-url-yay.firebaseio.com/')
.service('fbRef', function(fbURL) {
  return new Firebase(fbURL)
})
.service('fbAuth', function($q, $firebase, $firebaseAuth, fbRef) {
  var auth;
  return function () {
      if (auth) return $q.when(auth);
      var authObj = $firebaseAuth(fbRef);
      if (authObj.$getAuth()) {
        return $q.when(auth = authObj.$getAuth());
      }
      var deferred = $q.defer();
      authObj.$authAnonymously().then(function(authData) {
          auth = authData;
          deferred.resolve(authData);
      });
      return deferred.promise;
  }
})

.service('Projects', function($q, $firebase, fbRef, fbAuth) {
  var self = this;
  this.fetch = function () {
    if (this.projects) return $q.when(this.projects);
    return fbAuth().then(function(auth) {
      var deferred = $q.defer();
      var ref = fbRef.child('projects/' + auth.auth.uid);
      var $projects = $firebase(ref);
      ref.on('value', function(snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.val() === null) {
          $projects.$set(window.projectsArray);
        }
        self.projects = $projects.$asArray();
        deferred.resolve(self.projects);
      });
      return deferred.promise;
    });
  };
})

.config(function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider
    .when('/', {
      controller:'ListCtrl',
      templateUrl:'list.html',
      resolve: {
        projects: function (Projects) {
          return Projects.fetch();
        }
      }
    })
    .when('/edit/:projectId', {
      controller:'EditCtrl',
      templateUrl:'detail.html'
    })
    .when('/new', {
      controller:'CreateCtrl',
      templateUrl:'detail.html'
    })
    .otherwise({
      redirectTo:'/'
    });
})

.controller('ListCtrl', function($scope, projects) {
  $scope.projects = projects;
})

.controller('CreateCtrl', function($scope, $location, Projects) {
  $scope.save = function() {
      Projects.projects.$add($scope.project).then(function(data) {
          $location.path('/');
      });
  };
})

.controller('EditCtrl',
  function($scope, $location, $routeParams, Projects) {
    var projectId = $routeParams.projectId,
        projectIndex;

    $scope.projects = Projects.projects;
    projectIndex = $scope.projects.$indexFor(projectId);
    $scope.project = $scope.projects[projectIndex];

    $scope.destroy = function() {
        $scope.projects.$remove($scope.project).then(function(data) {
            $location.path('/');
        });
    };

    $scope.save = function() {
        $scope.projects.$save($scope.project).then(function(data) {
           $location.path('/');
        });
    };
});
```

**Index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Angular</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular-resource.min.js">
    </script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular-route.min.js">
   </script>
    <script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/js/client/2.0.4/firebase.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/libs/angularfire/0.9.0/angularfire.min.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body style="padding:20px;">
    <div ng-app="project" class="ng-scope"></div>
      <div ng-view></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: whew, i'm sorry you have to work with this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright, a few things are going on here:

#### Suggestions

1. AngularFire was updated to [1.1.1](https://cdn.firebase.com/libs/angularfire/1.1.1/angularfire.min.js) and `$firebase` is now deprecated. Use [`$firebaseObject`](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/api.html#angularfire-firebaseobject) and [`$firebaseArray`](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/api.html#angularfire-firebasearray) instead.
2. There is no need to do all that stuff in your `Projects` service and return a promise. `$firebaseObject` and `$firebaseArray` return promises.

#### Example

Check out this [PLNKR](http://plnkr.co/edit/1mVdZTKTqzzF3Iw1RXWI?p=preview) I made showing a working version of what you're trying to accomplish.

- It's tied to one of my public Firebase instances.
- You can create a new piece of data and see it on the home page.

#### JavaScript:

```
(function(angular) {
  angular.module('project', ['firebase', 'ngRoute'])
  .value('fbURL', 'https://sb-plnkr.firebaseio.com/so:28942661')

  .service('fbRef', function(fbURL) {
    return new Firebase(fbURL)
  })

  .service('fbAuth', function($q, $firebaseAuth, fbRef) {
    var auth;
    return function () {
      if (auth) return $q.when(auth);
      var authObj = $firebaseAuth(fbRef);
      if (authObj.$getAuth()) {
        return $q.when(auth = authObj.$getAuth());
      }
      var deferred = $q.defer();
      authObj.$authAnonymously().then(function(authData) {
          auth = authData;
          deferred.resolve(authData);
      });
      return deferred.promise;
    }
  })

  .service('Projects', function($q, $firebaseArray, fbRef) {
    this.sync = $firebaseArray(fbRef);
    this.sync.$loaded().then(function(data) {
      var projects = data;
    });
    return this.sync;
  })

  .controller('ListCtrl', function($scope, $location, Projects) {
    Projects.$loaded().then(function(data){
      $scope.projects = data;
    });
  })

  .controller('CreateCtrl', function($scope, $location, Projects) {
    console.log("CreateCtrl");
    $scope.save = function() {
      console.debug("Adding");
      if ($scope.project && $scope.project.content !== '') {
        Projects.$add($scope.project).then(function(ref) {
          console.log("Added ref",ref);
          $location.path('/');
        }).catch(function(errorObject){
          console.error(errorObject);
        });
      } else {
        alert("You have to enter something.");
      }
    };
  })

  .controller('EditCtrl',function($scope, $location, $routeParams, Projects) {
    var projectId = $routeParams.projectId,
        projectIndex;

    $scope.init = function(){
      Projects.$loaded().then(function(data) {
        $scope.projects = data;
        console.info("EditCtrl - Projects.$loaded():",data);
        projectIndex = $scope.projects.$indexFor(projectId);
        $scope.project = $scope.projects[projectIndex];
      });
    }

    $scope.destroy = function() {
      $scope.projects.$remove($scope.project).then(function(data) {
        $location.path('/');
      });
    };

    $scope.save = function() {
      $scope.projects.$save($scope.project).then(function(data) {
       $location.path('/');
      });
    };
  })

  .config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $routeProvider
      .when('/', {
        controller:'ListCtrl',
        templateUrl:'list.html'
      })
      .when('/edit/:projectId', {
        controller:'EditCtrl',
        templateUrl:'detail.html'
      })
      .when('/new', {
        controller:'CreateCtrl',
        templateUrl:'create.html'
      })
      .otherwise({
        redirectTo:'/'
      });

      $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
  });
})(window.angular);
```

#### HTML:

(index.html)

```
<body style="padding:20px;">
  <div ng-app="project" ng-controller="EditCtrl">
    <a href="new">New</a>
    <div ng-view></div>
  </div>
</body>
```

(create.html)

```
<h2>Create</h2>
<button ng-click="save()">Save</button>
```

(list.html)

```
<h2>List</h2>
<div ng-repeat="(key,data) in projects">
  <span>$scope.projects[<span ng-bind="key"></span>].content : </span>
  <span ng-bind="data.content"></span>
</div>
<h2>Object Debug</h2>
<pre ng-bind="projects | json"></pre>
```

---

#### Hope that helps!

Comment: Honored to hear that from you @Kato :) Thanks for all the hard work your team has put into 1.0.0 - it's a game changer.

Comment: @Kato Do you have any recommendations on where to find up-to-data tutorials? Basically anything that doesn't use outdated APIs.

Comment: @NOPENOPENOPE You're most welcome. Thoughts on your last question: I think getting past this roadblock was more about understanding AngularJS in general - promises/services/factories etc. The Firebase team always keeps docs up to date, and those docs have lots of awesome snippets. AngularFire 1.0.0 was _just_ released a couple days ago, so it makes sense that examples on AngularJS site for AngularFire are outdated. It's good habit to check the official docs for whatever you're using, first, before going to examples. https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/guide/

Comment: For example, on the [intro-to-angularfire](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/guide/intro-to-angularfire.html) page, you can see an example for creating a basic factory for an `$firebaseArray` that is pretty similar to what we did here. You can _even run the code sample right in the docs!_ And there are even more examples on the next page, [synchronized-objects](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/guide/synchronized-objects.html).

Comment: And last but not least... The [synchronized-arrays full example](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/guide/synchronized-arrays.html#section-full-example) shows a use case of the `.$loaded()` method. Again, you can run/edit all of these examples right in the Firebase docs. _pretty cool_ Each of the getting started guides have these executable examples that you can tinker with to your liking :) When you are done with the guides, definitely read over the **[complete AngularFire API documentation](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/api.html)** as well